# java source parsing library for python

Tags: java, python

Ive been searching for a while and can't seem to find what im looking for.  What I want to do is write a python script to report problems and enforce code standards in Java code.  Everything I have found so far has been things to translate java into python or python into java and that isn't really what I want.  Im looking for a python library that can parse a multi-thousand class project and present the source itself in python in such a way where I can write rules something like

- every class must have class level javadoc
- every class must have a @primaryContactName tag in class level javadoc
- every class must have a @primaryContactEmail tag in class level javadoc
- the authorized 3rd party library list is {1,2,3,4,5} are any libraries other than this
  list used
- all lists and maps fully type safe.
- bla bla bla

I reallize that I can get a great deal of this info from javac with very little effort, and I may investigate using javac to make version work, but im looking to do something a bit more advanced where I can build in real analytics

I have done similar with XDoclet in the past, but that was primarily used to mantain metadata in the source code about what systems it was accessing and such, nothing really to this analytics level im looking for now.

Anyone come across a python library that would help out with this?  I would consider other languages (java, c, etc) its simply in my current situation, python is easier to work with than anything else.

Comment: Please consider other languages. Javadoc does it best, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/index.html

Comment: Thats certainly still on the table.  We want to build a reporting/metadata system into the code to easily answer questions like how many systems access external interface X.  a custom doclet is the obvious choice for that, but im just not sure if the API can give me the deep code structure control im looking for.  Ill look at the api again tho, its been a few years since I played with it.

Comment: the antlr github repository has a simple example for parsing java via python: https://github.com/antlr/examples-v3/tree/master/Python/java